# Efficient method for checking monotonicity in array Julia?

Tags: arrays, function, julia

Trying to come up with a fast way to make sure a  is monotonic in Julia.

The slow (and obvious) way to do it that I have been using is something like this:

```
function check_monotonicity(
    timeseries::Array,
    column::Int
)
    current = timeseries[1,column]
    for row in 1:size(timeseries, 1)
        if timeseries[row,column] > current 
            return false
        end 
        current = copy(timeseries[row,column])
    end 
    return true
end
```

So that it works something like this:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia>mono_matrix = hcat(collect(0:0.1:10), rand(Uniform(0.4,0.6),101),reverse(collect(0.0:0.1:10.0)))
101×3 Matrix{Float64}:
  0.0  0.574138  10.0
  0.1  0.490671   9.9
  0.2  0.457519   9.8
  0.3  0.567687   9.7
  ⋮              
  9.8  0.513691   0.2
  9.9  0.589585   0.1
 10.0  0.405018   0.0
julia> check_monotonicity(mono_matrix, 2)
false
```

And then for the opposite example:

```
julia> check_monotonicity(mono_matrix, 3)
true
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this for long time series?

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding among new Julia users that writing out a loop, and excplicitly carrying out the operations must be slow. But that is not the case! A well-written loop is normally the the most efficient solution, moreso than stringing together several library calls. This is unlike many other high-level languages!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation is certainly not slow! It is very nearly optimally fast. You should definitely get rid of the `copy`. Though it doesn't hurt when the matrix elements are just plain data, it can be bad in other cases, perhaps for `BigInt` for example.

This is close to your original effort, but also more robust with respect to indexing and array types:

```
function ismonotonic(A::AbstractMatrix, column::Int, cmp = <)
    current = A[begin, column] # begin instead of 1
    for i in axes(A, 1)[2:end] # skip the first element
        newval = A[i, column] # don't use copy here
        cmp(newval, current) && return false
        current = newval
    end
    return true
end
```

Another tip: You don't need to use `collect`. In fact, you should almost *never* use collect. Do this instead (I removed `Uniform` since I don't have Distributions.jl):

```
mono_matrix = hcat(0:0.1:10, rand(101), reverse(0:0.1:10)) # or 10:-0.1:0
```

Or perhaps this is better, since you have more control over the numer of elements in the range:

```
mono_matrix = hcat(range(0, 10, 101), rand(101), range(10, 0, 101))
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
1.7.2> ismonotonic(mono_matrix, 3)
false

1.7.2> ismonotonic(mono_matrix, 3, >=)
true

1.7.2> ismonotonic(mono_matrix, 1)
true
```

Comment: This is great thank you! especially the recommendation re: collect, that's great

Answer (score 5):

In mathematics typically we define a series to be monotonic if it is non-decreasing or non-increasing. If this is what you want then do:

```
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 2), rev=true)
```

to check if it is non-increasing, and:

```
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 2))
```

to check if it is non-decreasing.

If you want a decreasing check do:

```
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 3), rev=true, lt = <=)
```

for decreasing, but treating `0.0` and `-0.0` as equal or

```
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 3), lt = <=)
```

for increasing, but treating `0.0` and `-0.0` as equal.

If you want to distinguish `0.0` and `-0.0` then do respectively:

```
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 3), rev=true, lt = (x, y) -> isequal(x, y) || isless(x, y))
issorted(view(mono_matrix, :, 3), lt = (x, y) -> isequal(x, y) || isless(x, y))
```

Comment: Note that this seems to be significantly slower than the OP's code.

Comment: It should not as `issorted` internally is almost exactly the same as the function you have written in your post (it just uses iteration protocol instead, as your implementation would need to be fixed for collections of length 0 and 1 for full generality). I have not benchmarked it though. Maybe the compiler is not fully optimizing out the view, but I expect it should.

Comment: With `m = reshape(sort(rand(100)), :, 1)` using `@btime issorted($m; lt=<)` is the same speed, but the default is `isless` which takes 3x as long.